# Seemingly inconsistent slicing behavior in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I ran across something that seemed to me like inconsistent behavior in Numpy slices. Specifically, please consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)   # a 2d numpy array
y = np.array([1,2,2])           # vector that will be used to index the array

b = a[np.arange(len(a)),y]      # a vector (what I want)
c = a[:,y]                      # a matrix ??
```

I wanted to obtain a vector such that the i-th element is `a[i,y[i]]`. I tried two things (`b` and `c` above) and was surprised that `b` and `c` are not the same... in fact one is a vector and the other is a matrix! I was under the impression that `:` was shorthand for "all elements" but apparently the meaning is somewhat more subtle.

After trial and error I somewhat understand the difference now (`b == np.diag(c)`), but would appreciate clarification on *why* they are different, what exactly using `:` implies, and how to understand when to use either case.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think this is inconsistent?

Comment: Inconsistent because in my use of Python before, I have been trained to think of `:` to mean "all elements". When I index an array, I expect `myArr[:]` and  `myArr[np.arrage(len(myArr))]` to yield the same result. And it does, so I was surprised when this did not generalize to several dimensions.

Comment: @BradSolomon I know they yield the same thing, which is why I expected `:` to mean the same thing as `np.arange(len(a))` :). Which it does in 1 dimension, but not in two or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass

```
np.arange(len(a)), y
```

You can view the result as being all the indexed *pairs* for the zipped elements you passed.  In this case, indexing by `np.arange(len(a))` and `y`

```
np.arange(len(a))
# [0, 1, 2]
y
# [1, 2, 2]
```

effectively takes elements: (0, 1), (1, 2), and (2, 2).

```
print(a[0, 1], a[1, 2], a[2, 2])  # 0th, 1st, 2nd elements from each indexer
# 1 5 8
```

In the second case, you take the entire slice along the first dimension.  (Nothing before the colon.)  So this is all elements *along the 0th axis*.  You then specify with `y` that you want the 1st, 2nd, and 2nd element along each row.  (0-indexed.)

As you pointed out, it may seem a bit unintuitive that the results are different given that the individual elements of the slice are equivalent:

```
a[:] == a[np.arange(len(a))]
```

and

```
a[:y] == a[:y]
```

However, NumPy [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) cares what *type* of data structure you pass when indexing (tuples, integers, etc).  Things can become hairy very quickly.

The detail behind that is this: first consider *all* NumPy indexing to be of the general form `x[obj]`, where `obj` is the evaluation of whatever you passed.  How NumPy "behaves" depends on what type of object `obj` is:

> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a
>   non-tuple sequence object, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool),
>   or **a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type
>   integer or bool).**
>   ...
>   The definition of advanced indexing means that x[(1,2,3),] is
>   fundamentally different than x[(1,2,3)]. The latter is equivalent to
>   x[1,2,3] which will trigger basic selection while the former will
>   trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this occurs.

In your first case, `obj = np.arange(len(a)),y`, a tuple that fits the bill in bold above.  This triggers advanced indexing and forces the behavior described above.

As for the second case,  `[:,y]`

> When there is at least one slice (:), ellipsis (...) or np.newaxis in
>   the index (or the array has more dimensions than there are advanced
>   indexes), then the behaviour can be more complicated. **It is like
>   concatenating the indexing result for each advanced index element.**

Demonstrated:

```
# Concatenate the indexing result for each advanced index element.
np.vstack((a[0, y], a[1, y], a[2, y]))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand advanced indexing (with lists or arrays) without understanding broadcasting.

```
In [487]: a=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [488]: idx = np.array([1,2,2])
```

Index with a (3,) and (3,) producing shape (3,) result:

```
In [489]: a[np.arange(3),idx]
Out[489]: array([1, 5, 8])
```

Index with (3,1) and (3,), result is (3,3)

```
In [490]: a[np.arange(3)[:,None],idx]
Out[490]: 
array([[1, 2, 2],
       [4, 5, 5],
       [7, 8, 8]])
```

The slice `:` does basically the same thing.   There are subtle differences, but here it's the same.

```
In [491]: a[:,idx]
Out[491]: 
array([[1, 2, 2],
       [4, 5, 5],
       [7, 8, 8]])
```

`ix_` does the same thing, converting the (3,) & (3,) to (3,1) and (1,3):

```
In [492]: np.ix_(np.arange(3),idx)
Out[492]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]), array([[1, 2, 2]]))
```

A broadcasted sum might help visualize the two cases:

```
In [495]: np.arange(3)*10+idx
Out[495]: array([ 1, 12, 22])
In [496]: np.sum(np.ix_(np.arange(3)*10,idx),axis=0)
Out[496]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  2],
       [11, 12, 12],
       [21, 22, 22]])
```